# Dual of $\ell^p$ Direct sum

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, direct-sum, dual-spaces

I am asked to show that the $\ell^p$-direct sum of a sequence of Banach Spaces $X_n$ is isometrically isomorphic to the $\ell^q$ direct sum of $X_n^*$ where $X_n^*$ is the dual of $X_n$ for each $n$ respectively. (Here $p$, $q$ are conjugate indices with $1\leq p<\infty$).
So far I have tried the case $p>1$, and I am trying to adapt the proof of $(\ell^p)^*$ being isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^q$ but this isn't getting anywhere.
Could someone please give any hints?

EDITED by idonknow: Fix $1\leq p<\infty.$ The $\ell^p$-direct sum of a sequence of Banach spaces $X_n,$  denoted as $\left( \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right)_{\ell^p},$ means that for every $x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in \left( \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right)_{\ell^p},$ we have 
$$\|x\| = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|x_n\|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

Comment: There are two parts of the proof: easy ($\oplus X_n^*$ acts on $\oplus X_n$) and hard (there are no other functionals). Any problems with the first part?

Comment: What is the $l^p$ direct sum of the $X_n?$

Comment: Could you define what you mean by $\ell^p$ direct sum?

Comment: Maybe each $X_n$ should be a reflexive Banach space ?

Comment: @Idonknow But in this problem we have an infinite sequence of Banach spaces, right? The definition of the norm would then be for those $x$ for which the sum converges I suppose.

Comment: I think there something missing in this problem. Assume that $X_n\{0\}$ for all $n>1$ except then , $X\equiv X_1$  from this problem we have that $X_1$ and $X_1^*$ must be isometrics. which is curious. Since given a random Banach space it is not always clear how to define a map from the space to its dual

Comment: in the above comment Asume that $X_n\equiv \{0\}$ for all $n>1$

Comment: @GuyFsone I don't see how it is saying that.

Comment: @Idonknow It should be $\left( \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right)_{\ell^p},$ right?

Comment: YES But  what if we  Assum all the spaces are trivial except one of them.?

Comment: @GuyFsone I don't see the problem. Why do you say $X_1,X_1^*$ are isometric?

Comment: @Idonknow A proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530371/help-proving-that-a-banach-space-is-reflexive). [Assuming that the intention here is, as indicated by the question title, to show that _the dual_ of the $\ell^p$-direct sum is isometrically isomorphic to the $\ell^q$-direct sum of the duals. As written in the first sentence of the question body, the assertion is easily seen to be wrong.]

Comment: @zhw. In the case whre $X_n\equiv \{0\}$ for $n>1$ $X\equiv X_1 $ and  $X^*\equiv X^*_1 $ and  the $\ell^p$ norm reduce to the norm of $X_1$ . Same for the $\ell^q$ norm on $X^*$ reduce norm of $X^*_1$. Is that not correct?

Comment: @DanielFischer I saw your answer and it confirms my doubt . as part of assumptions one should assum $X_n$ to reflexive and the asked isometry from the body question seem to be wrong. Thank you

Comment: @GuyFsone I see what you mean now, sorry for the confusion. I hadn't even read the first sentence carefully, I had just assumed the result to be proved was what "it should be", as Daniel Fischer said.