# inner product of a sequence of banach spaces and its dual space

Tags: banach-spaces, inner-products, dual-spaces

[image]

I'm working on (a), (b) and (c) of this exercise.

To (a): T.p.: every Cauchy sequence in E has a convergent subsequence with limit in E.

So, take $(x_n)_n \in E $. $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence of sequences: $(x_n)_n = ((x_{1n})_n,(x_{2n})_n,(x_{3n})_n,...)$, where $(x_{in})_n \in E_i \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let now $(x_n)_n \in E $ be cauchy, then I get for $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary and n, m sufficiently large: $\epsilon > \lVert ((x_{1n})_n,(x_{2n})_n,(x_{3n})_n,...) - ((x_{1m})_m,(x_{2m})_m,(x_{3m})_m,...) \rVert = (\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty (\lVert x_{in} - x_{im} \rVert)^p)^\frac{1}{p} > \lVert  x_{in} - x_{im} \rVert$, so $x_{in}$ is cauchy in $E_i$ with limit $y_i$.
Now I wanted to show that $(y_n)_n$ is the limit of $(x_n)_n$, but I'm not able to do so, because the sum is not going to $N$, but to $\infty$.

How can I do this?

And could you please help me with (b) and (c)?
I'm struggling how to start there..

Comment: I guess [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/530452) (in particular the second part, starting with "More generally") could help.

Comment: I'm still working on it, but it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For (a):

Let $\{\{S(n)_{j,k}\}_j\}_k$ be the partial sequence of $\{\{x_{j,k}\}_j\}_k$; that is, for all $k$, $$S(n)_{\cdot,k}\in\sideset{}{_p}\bigoplus_{j=1}^n{E_j}$$ with, for all $j<n$, $S(n)_{j,k}=x_{j,k}$.  You have shown that, for any $n$, $S(n)_{j,k}\to S_{j,\infty}$.

But the rest of the sequence is small!  To be more precise: because $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{x_{j,k}^p}<\infty$, for any $\epsilon$, $\sum_{j=J(\epsilon)}^{\infty}{x_{j,k}^p}<\epsilon$. We will abuse notation and write this last inequality as $|\{x_{j,k}\}_j-\{S(J(k,\epsilon))_{j,k}\}_j|<\epsilon^p$ for some $J(k,\epsilon)$.

The final ingredient necessary is to note that although our quantifiers form a loop (we need $J$ to pick $K$ and vice-versa), we can elide the problem by approximating $\{x_{j,k}\}_j$ with a nearby $\{x_{j,\kappa}\}_j$ by Cauchyness.

So, fix $\epsilon$.  There exists $K_1\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that, for all $k\geq K_1$, $|\{x_{j,K_1}\}_j-\{x_{j,k}\}_k|_p<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$.  There exists $N_1\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that, for any $n\geq N_1$, $|\{x_{j,K_1}\}_j-\{S(n)_{j,K_1}\}_j|<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$.  And there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that, for any $n\geq N_2$, $|\{x_{j,\infty}\}_j-\{S(n)_{j,\infty}\}_j|<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$.  Finally, let $N=\max{(N_1,N_2)}$.  Then there exists $K_2$ such that, for any $k\geq K_2$, $|\{S(n)_{j,k}\}_j-\{S(n)_{j,\infty}\}_j|_p<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$.

Thus, for any $k\geq\max{(K_1,K_2)}$, \begin{align*}
|\{x_{j,k}\}_j-\{x_{j,\infty}\}_j|_p&=|\{S(N)_{j,k}\}_j-\{x_{S(N),\infty}\}_j|_p+{}\\
&\phantom{= |}|(\{x_{j,k}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,k}\}_j)-(\{x_{j,\infty}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,\infty}\}_j)|_p \\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{4}+|(\{x_{j,k}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,k}\}_j)-(\{x_{j,\infty}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,\infty}\}_j)|_p \\
&\leq\frac{\epsilon}{4}+|\{x_{j,k}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,k}\}_j|_p+|\{x_{j,\infty}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,\infty}\}_j|_p \\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{4}+|\{x_{j,k}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,k}\}_j|_p+\frac{\epsilon}{4} \\
&\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}+|\{x_{j,k}\}_j-\{x_{j,K_1}\}_j|_p+|\{x_{j,K_1}\}_j-\{S(N)_{j,K_1}\}_j|_p \\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{4}+\frac{\epsilon}{4}=\epsilon
\end{align*}

(You'll notice that this proof is identical to the case $E_j=\mathbb{R}$.)

For (b): We remarked above that (a) was identical to $(\mathbb{R}^n;l^p)$.  The same holds here: you should be able to straightforwardly show that, if we interpret an element of $\sideset{}{_q}\bigoplus_{j=1}^{\infty}{E_j'}$ as a functional on $\sideset{}{_p}\bigoplus_{j=1}^{\infty}{E_j}$ with action given by termwise application and then an infinite sum the result is well-defined.  Conversely, given a functional in $\left(\sideset{}{_p}\bigoplus_{j=1}^{\infty}{E_j}\right)'$, the restriction, for all $k$ to $E_k\oplus\left(\sideset{}{_p}\bigoplus_{k\neq j=1}^{\infty}{0}\right)$ ought to give you an element of $E_k'$.  Furthermore, the action of the original functional is the sum of the functionals so generated.  Because $E_k'$ norms $E_k$, a double-application of Hölder's inequality ought to give you (a) that the sum defining $\sideset{}{_q}\bigoplus_{j=1}^{\infty}{E_j'}$ is satisfied by this construction and (b) the the bijection is norm-preserving.

I suppose you also need to prove linearity, but that takes no more than a line.

For (c): note that, by disjointness of $\{\Omega_n\}_n$, any $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ has a unique decomposition $f=\sum_n{\chi_{\Omega_n}f}$, where $\chi_{(\cdot)}$ is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).  The result should then follow from showing each $\chi_{\Omega_n}f\in L^p(\Omega_n)$ and definition-chasing.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me, you helped me a lot!
So I have (a) now, and I'm trying to solve (b). I managed to do the part with the isomorphism and I'm trying to prove that it is isometric now.
Let f be the linear mapping from $(\bigoplus E_i)'$ to $\bigoplus E_i'$.
One direction is that $\lVert f \rVert <= \lVert \sum_{n} (f_n) \rVert_q$, where $f(x_1 + x_2 + ..) = \sum_{n} f_n(x_n)$. Could you give me a hint how to prove the other direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I now did it similar like it's done [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj05Z3Zhq3UAhUBFxQKHVecDI8QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.berkeley.edu%2F~sarason%2FClass_Webpages%2Fsolutions_202B_assign10.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHXqJOIZyaeVPDnciq642bEu6HWIg) in exercise 36 (c). But I just don't understand why they can find these $x_i$ they use to get the other direction and moreover, that doesn't work for uncountably many $x_i$, does it?

Comment: In the link, they create the $x_i$ constructively; I think they've specialized to the $L^p(\Omega)$ case.  But in general, it either follows from Hahn-Banach or the definition of weak norm (don't have paper & pencil with me to figure out which way I'm going).  In the latter case, just take something such that $\phi(x)$ is close to its sup on the unit ball, then take limits.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by uncountably many $x_i$.  How do you take the sum of uncountably many numbers (without measure theory)?  You either end up with all but countably many terms vanishing, or $\infty$.

Comment: I'm very sorry I didn't want to write uncountably, I wanted to say infinitely.
Thanks for your comment, but could you please explain me, why that follows from Hahn-Banach? I just really don't see it.

Comment: I now asked it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314651/dual-of-a-direct-sum), if you want to answer. I hope that's okay, I thought I could explain better what my problem is this way..